# DevExpress XtraGrid Advanced Banded Grid View : band separator?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a couple of wide columns in the current grid:

```
         Mailing Name | Mailing Description | Mailing Date
```

and to keep the grid narrow, I changed the View to an Advanced Banded Grid View and stacked the columns like this:

```
          Mailing Name
          Mailing Date
          Mailing Description
```

Is there a way to insert some kind of separator between records?

```
          Holiday
          12/15/2011
          Holiday greetings to customers

          ==============================  <-- like this


          Summer Sale
          6/15/2011
          sale on BBQ grills flyer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the distance between rows: set the [RowSeparatorHeight](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowSeparatorHeighttopic) property to the desired separator height. Also you can color this area via the [Appearance.RowSeparator](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridViewAppearances_RowSeparatortopic).BackColor property.